# How do you remove passwords from files INSIDE a zip file?

Tags: passwords, zip

I have a zip file that has multiple password-protected files within it, all with the same password. Is there a way for me to automatically remove the passwords from the files within it?

Comment: What types of files are inside the zip? What have you tried? Step one is you'll need to unzip the files. Everything after that depends on what sort of files they are inside.

Comment: No. You can extract the files *manually* and then put them into one zip file without password, though. With 7-Zip, once you put in a single password, it should enable you to extract *all* the files at once.